# What fantasy book series has magic talismans made by a tribe that hates mages?

Tags: story-identification

I’m trying to find a fantasy book series. The things I remember are:

- To use magic they needed talisman. The only people who make them belong to a tribe that hates the mages.
- You follow a boy who lives with this tribe. He picks a fight with a mage and steals this ancient talisman.
- You follow him when he learns to use magic. The talisman he stole contains a spirit who is his ancestor.

Edit: I remember that the protagonist become in-love with the princess (cliche i know), he goes to a magic school, next to another school (soldier school). He goes there with a friend in the tribe that get pissed when he are forced to learn this type of magic. Since the tribe got their type of magic. Nature magic i think.

The story in the first book is about him hiding in the slums near the tribes since the mages want that amulet/talisman, since its one of the strongest and did belong to a hated person.

Well: Since i started to write more about the book, i found out the name of the first book: The demon king. by: Cinda Williams Chima.

Thanks all ^^

Comment: Any other details spring to mind? For example, when did you read it? How many books did you read, out of how many in the series?

Comment: Based on you finding the title and author you can deduce the series "The Seven Realms" from google?

Answer (score 5):

The original poster has stated that the series is "[The Seven Realms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven_Realms)" by Cinda Williams Chima, the first book being *[The Demon King](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6342491-the-demon-king)*.

[image: Book cover of "The Demon King"]

> 16-year-old Han Alister encounters three underage wizards setting fire to the sacred mountain of Hanalea. Alister is unaware that this will lead to a series of events that threaten to consume the world in chaos. To prevent the wizard Micah from using a magical amulet against him, Alister steals it from the wizard during a battle. Later, Alister learns that the amulet has an evil history, and it once belonged to the Demon King. The Demon King is an evil sorcerer who almost destroyed the world a millennia ago. Now, the wizards will stop at nothing to get their amulet back.